# Using an existing S3 bucket in AWS SAM template

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am using AWS SAM template for deployment of python AWS lambdas. The trigger for these functions are from existing S3 buckets. But in SAM template I am unable to use existing buckets (only new bucket creation is supported), hence I'am creating the trigger manually.

Is there any way we could incorporate this in SAM template ?

Comment: Not sure about sam, but since sam is based on cloudformation (CFN), maybe you could import it? CFN supports [importing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html) buckets into stacks.

Comment: you can't use an existing bucket with sam. It's a limitation mention [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/develop/versions/2016-10-31.md#s3).
You can try the workaround from this [comment](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/124#issuecomment-511779961).

Comment: In 2024, Just trying to understand it is still a restriction with SAM. If someone know an update, please help